# How to set Socket timeout of fail connecting

Tags: android, sockets, connection, timeout

Im trying to connect to socket `socket = new Socket(server , port);`, but if the server is not availabe I need to set a timeout of fail connection. 
Default timeout is **3min** , for example if i start connecting in **11:50:22**, error will be present only in **11:53:31**. See log:

```
    12-03 11:50:22.519: E/InternetIntentService(23897): Start connecting to localhost:9999
    12-03 11:53:31.869: W/System.err(23897): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /localhost (port 9999): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

How to change this **3min** to **10sec**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Socket` with the no-args constructor and then call [`connect(endpoint, timeout);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)):

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.connect(endpoint, timeout);
```

Note that contrary to the Javadoc, zero doesn't mean infinity, it means the platform default (around a minute), and that you can only use this technique to decrease the platform default, not to increase it.